# Neo4j: Failing batched cypher queries with a non 2xx HTTP response code

Tags: rest, neo4j, cypher

When you use the [REST batch operations endpoint](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-batch-ops.html) to submit multiple queries the process is transactional. From the documentation:

"This service is transactional. If any of the operations performed fails (returns a non-2xx HTTP status code), the transaction will be rolled back and all changes will be undone."

I would like to submit multiple queries and if the first one fails, rollback the whole transaction. An example of this might be like the following:

- Authenticate user
- Update the users public profile

If the authenticate user query fails to find an authenticated user I would like that cypher query to get Neo4j to return a non 2xx code so the second query will not run. Because the first query is a valid query it will not make Neo4j return a non 2xx code, rather it will return null as it does not find an authenticated user.

Is there a way to do this?

Possible workarounds for this (so one of these doesn't get added as the answer):

- Combine the two queries, the downside to this is added complexity and code duplication
- Use a transactional approach, the downside to this is extra http requests.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [transactional Cypher Endpoint](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-transactional.html).

There, start by POSTing your auth query to `/db/data/transaction`, if you don't find a user DELETE the tx-URL `/db/data/transaction/<txid>`. Otherwise POST the update-queries to `/db/data/transaction/<txid>/commit`.